# What hardware do I need to monitor mobile traffic?

Tags: mobile

What kind of hardware would I need to monitor data sent between a mobile handset and a base-station?

Comment: A good read on how to intercepting GSM traffic http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-08/Steve-DHulton/Presentation/bh-dc-08-steve-dhulton.pdf

Comment: @AliAhmad nice slides, but it seems to suggest that the gear is all in at least the tens of thousands of dollars range.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options, dedicated commercial hardware about which I know little (*Nexus Telecom* is one vendor) other than it's improbably expensive; and the CCC method: https://svn.berlin.ccc.de/projects/airprobe/wiki/hardware (site uses a CAcert.org signed cert).

It seems you can get off to a good start with GNU Radio and a USRP board (sub $1000).